# Defining \nextslide in overprint environment in beamer

Tags: beamer, overlays

We all use the `\onslide` command inside the `overprint` environment in `beamer`. However, I find that assigning hard coded slide values, like `\onslide<5>` in this environment is really cumbersome. This situation becomes difficult whenever we have to insert a new slide in the middle of twenty some overlay slides. We have to manually renumber every subsequent slide after a new slide is inserted. That is why, I tried to define a `\nextslide` command in `beamer`.

The idea is very simple, the `\nextslide` command will increment a predefined counter and will use this value with the `\onslide` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{slidecounter}
\setcounter{slidecounter}{0}
\def\nextslide{\addtocounter{slidecounter}{1}\onslide<\value{slidecounter}>}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

  \begin{overprint}
    \nextslide
    On one

    \nextslide
    On two

  \end{overprint}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I understand that I still need to implement resetting the counter at the start of `overprint` environment once I am successful with this part.

However, whenever I run the code with `pdflatex`, it keeps on generating page after page, which I have to interrupt with `Ctrl-C`.

> [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] [2] [3] [4] [5]
>   [6] [7] [8] [9] [10] [11] [12] [13] [14] [15] [16] [17] [18] [19] [20]
>   [21] [22] [23] [24] [25] [26] [27] [28] [29] [30] [31] [32] [33] [34]
>   [35] [36] [37] [38] [39] [40] [41] [42] [43] [44] [45] [46] [47] [48]
>   [49] [50] [51] [52] [53] [54] [55] [56] [57] [58] [59] [60] [61] [62]
>   [63] [64] [65] [66] [67] [68] [69] [70] [71] [72] [73] [74]^C !
>   Interruption. \pgfsysprotocol@literalbuffered ...tocol@temp {{#1
>                                                     \space }}\expandafter \pgf... l.20 \end{frame}
>                    ? x

The `beamer` code is too myriad for me to find out where this infinite loop is happening.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's what the `+` overlay specification is made for (cf. [the `beamer` user guide, section 9.6.4](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf#subsubsection.9.6.4)):

> The effect of the `+`-sign is the following: You can use it in any overlay specification at any point where you would usually use a number. If a `+`-sign is encountered, it is replaced by the current value of the LaTeX counter `beamerpauses`, which is 1 at the beginning of the frame. Then the counter is increased by 1, though it is only increased once for every overlay specification, even if the specification contains multiple `+`-signs (they are replaced by the same number).

So your MWE can be solved with

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  \begin{overprint}
    \onslide<+>
    On one
    \onslide<+>
    On two
    \onslide<+>
    On three
  \end{overprint}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh, goodness, I feel like a fool. Still, I would like to know what caused the infinite loop.

Comment: @MMA The problem is that the slide is compiled each time an overlay is typeset, so `slidecounter` is increased by 2 and such produces new overlays: For example, on the second overlay, `\onslide<3>` and `\onslide<4>` are executed, such creating two new pages etc. If you use  `\setcounter{slidecounter}{0}` at the beginning of the frame, this won't happen and your MWE will produce the expected result.